# How do I plot a gigantic function easily on WA?

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I need to graph a gigantic function on WA, that has other functions inside it and some constants with preassigned values that come up a lot! For example:

W = Q*b*BesselK...., in which Q is an equation like Q = x*b + ..., and b has a said value.

Is there a way to write this as

Being b = 10 and Q = x*b + ...,

Plot[Q*b*BesselK]?

I'm new to Wolfram Mathematica and this would help me a lot.

Comment: I guess your question is better suited for [*Mathematica Stack Exchange*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you, didn't know about it.

Comment: @SangchulLee Questions about WolframAlpha are [explicitly off-topic there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Arthur, Thank you for letting me know of that. :)